# Getting a jQuery library to work in WordPress & Avada

Tags: customization, jquery, templates

I am creating a custom page template that would include [this jQuery multi-selector](http://loudev.com/#home) on it, but I cannot seem to make it work no matter what I do.

Both CSS and JS files seem to get added to the theme header file but this is what I keep seeing when I paste the selector code:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/slgW0.png]

My template file code:

```
<select id='pre-selected-options' multiple='multiple'>
    <option value='elem_1' selected>elem 1</option>
    <option value='elem_2'>elem 2</option>
    <option value='elem_3'>elem 3</option>
    <option value='elem_4' selected>elem 4</option>
    <option value='elem_100'>elem 100</option>
 </select>
```

My functions.php file:

```
function wptuts_scripts_load_cdn()
{
    wp_register_script( 'multi-select', 'https://www.mywebsite.com/selector/js/jquery.multi-select.js', array(), null, false );

    wp_register_script( 'bs4', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha/js/bootstrap.min.js', array(), null, false );

}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wptuts_scripts_load_cdn' );

function wptuts_styles_with_the_lot()
{
    // Register the style like this for a theme:
    wp_register_style( 'custom-style', 'https://www.mywebsite.com/selector/css/multi-select.css', array(), '20120208', 'all' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wptuts_styles_with_the_lot' );
```

I'm using [Avada theme](http://avada.theme-fusion.com/) if that matters.

What might be the problem here?

Comment: Where are you initializing jQuery Multiselect? E.g.: `$('#pre-selected-options').multiSelect();` I see that you're including the main library, but you need to load the JS (and specify dependencies, 'jquery' and 'multi-select' )  that attaches the Multiselect library to your select element. BTW, the 'multi-select' script should specify `jquery` as a dependency.

Comment: I initialized Multiselect in the template file. I know it's not idea, but considering my [lack of] Javascript knowledge, this is the only option that didn't give me console errors. I tried everything, and nothing seems to be working. Can you please explain how to specify dependencies in this case?

Comment: Take a look at the docs for [`wp_enqueue_script`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/), particularly the `$deps` argument. Also, replace the use of `wp_register_script` with `wp_enqueue_script` and use `wp_enqueue_style` instead of `wp_register_style`. Registering a script or stylesheet does not actually enqueue it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a tweaked version of the original code. `get_template_directory_uri()` is used instead of hard coding the URLs, the scripts and styles are enqueud rather than just being registered, and the dependencies are specified.

```
<?php
function wptuts_scripts_load_cdn() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'multi-select', get_template_directory_uri() . '/selector/js/jquery.multi-select.js', array( 'jquery' ), null, false );

    // JavaScript for theme. Presumably where you'd want to initialize the multi-select element.
    //wp_enqueue_script( 'theme-scripts', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/theme-scripts.js', array( 'jquery', 'multi-select' ), null, false );

    wp_enqueue_script( 'bs4', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha/js/bootstrap.min.js', array(), null, false );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wptuts_scripts_load_cdn' );

function wptuts_styles_with_the_lot() {
    // Enqueue the style like this for a theme:
    wp_enqueue_style( 'custom-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/selector/css/multi-select.css', array(), '20120208' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wptuts_styles_with_the_lot' );
```